# JWT Retreiving the Authenticated user from a token in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, jwt

When I pass user's jwt token in the request header, I only get the user info which is in  that table

I have a relational database in which each users have data stored in another table.
JWT only returns the users details from the user's table (name, email etc. just that).

While fetching list of all users I can get their data stored in the other table but I don't know how to do it with jwt.

Can anyone guide me with that? I'm using Laravel

This is the User resource

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;
use App\History;
use App\Http\Resources\History as HistoryResource;

class Admin extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id'  => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'email' => $this->email,
            'history' => HistoryResource::collection($this->history)
        ];
    }
}
```

And this is the jwt controller for fetching user

```
public function getAuthenticatedUser()
{
    try {

        if (! $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()) {
            return response()->json(['user_not_found'], 404);
        }

    } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException $e) {

        return response()->json(['token_expired'], $e->getStatusCode());

    } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException $e) {

        return response()->json(['token_invalid'], $e->getStatusCode());

    } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException $e) {

        return response()->json(['token_absent'], $e->getStatusCode());

    }

    // the token is valid and we have found the user via the sub claim
    return response()->json(compact('user'));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()` returns a `User` and not  a User Resource (`Admin`).

You just need to generate the resource from the `$user` to fix:

```
$admin = new Admin($user);
return response()->json(['user' => $admin]);
```

Comment: It returns an empty array

Comment: can you verify that `$user` is valid before creating Admin resouce?  `dd($user)`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by simply doing this.

```
    $user = auth()->user();
    $admin = Admin::find($user);
    $return = AdminResource::collection($admin);   
    return response()->json($return);
```

It returned the logged in user